# Do non-compact Fano manifolds exist?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, fano-varieties

Suppose $(M,g, \omega)$ is a Kähler manifold with $\text{Ric}(g) = g$, i.e., $M$ is a Fano manifold. Is $M$ necessarily compact? If not, perhaps complete and Fano implies compact? I'd like to build a catalog of examples of Fano manifolds, so any input is appreciated.

Comment: For the first question, taking any compact Fano and deleting a point doesn't change the condition on the Ricci tensor. For the second, in what sense do you mean "complete"?

Comment: @Pop Complete in the sense of metric completeness.

Comment: Thank you. I asked because in algebraic geometry "complete" has an alternative meaning, essentially the same as "compact".

Comment: @Pop Complete is a dangerous word, I should've been more specific. At least complete is not as bad as "regular" which is so well-defined that we have 20 different inequivalent definitions for it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Bonnet Myers theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem), bounded positive Ricci curvature and complete Riemannian metric forces compact. David Wraith once explained to me that if the Ricci decays more slowly than quadratically in distance from a given point, on a complete Riemannian manifold, then the manifold is compact, a stronger result than Bonnet-Myers. Wraith's result does not have a published proof, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Ben

Comment: See these two classic papers by Calabi http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-67-03469-2 and Ambrose http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-57-02440-7 which cover the extension that you mentioned